# i want to push object into array of objects in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

im new to vue and im trying to get the whole concept of vue and how to use it, now im trying to learn lists.

JS:

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
    {Name: "qwe"},
    {Name: "qwe"},
    {Name: "zxc"},
    {Name: "qwe"},
    {Name: "asd"}
  ] },
  methods: {
      items.push({Name: "tyu"})
}
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <ol>
      <li v-for="item in items">{{item.Name}}</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: (1) Use `this.items.push(...)`. (2) You need a function declaration in the methods. Right now, you are not pushing anything into the array. (3) Do you want to push it on user interaction? When the component is created? When the component is mounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `properties` of `methods` property should be a function.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
    {Name: "qwe"},
    {Name: "qwe"},
    {Name: "zxc"},
    {Name: "qwe"},
    {Name: "asd"}
  ] },
  methods: {
      // Create a function
      addItem: () => {
         this.items.push({Name: "tyu"});
      }
  }
})
```

Now you need to call the `addItem` function.

**Using Button Click**

```
<button (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
```

or

```
<button v-on:click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
```

**On Load**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
    {Name: "qwe"},
    {Name: "qwe"},
    {Name: "zxc"},
    {Name: "qwe"},
    {Name: "asd"}
  ] },
  methods: {
      addItem: () => {
         this.items.push({Name: "tyu"});
      }
  },
  beforeMount(){
    // Call on page load.
    this.addItem()
  },
})
```

**Vue.Js** has an awesome **documentation** with **examples**. I strongly recommend you to read it.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/